# Scrapy - FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING Doesn't Work in Ubuntu Server

Tags: python, json, unicode, scrapy, export

Even though both my local and server scrapy versions are the same, setting `FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING = 'utf-8'` in the `settings.py` doesn't make change in the server for exporting the result in the `JSON` file.

What I've done in settings.py file :

```
FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING = 'utf-8'
```

Which command I run to get the result :

```
scrapy crawl spiderName -o file.json
```

What I get in return :

```
...
'content': u'\n                                  \r\nTruffle 
\u0628\u0627 \u0645\u0627\u0654\u0645\u0648'
           u'\u0631\u06cc\u062a 
\u0631\u0627\u062d\u062a\u200c\u062a\u0631 \u06a9\u0631\u062f\u0646 
\u0632'
           u'\u0646\u062f\u06af\u06cc 
\u062f\u0648\u0644\u0648\u067e\u0631\u0647\u0627\u06cc \u06a9\u0631\
           u06cc\u067e\u062a\u0648\u06a9\u
...
```

I do exactly the same process in my local machine and every unicode decode to `utf-8`.

What would you suggest?

Comment: What you show here isn't JSON, it's the `repr()` form of Python Unicode strings. Did you expect to get JSON? If so, this isn't an encoding problem, but some other configuration error.

Comment: Btw, you cannot "decode to UTF-8", you decode *from* UTF-8, or *encode* to UTF-8. Even though Python 2 actually allows you to do something like `u'a'.decode('utf-8')`, it is almost never what you really want. A `unicode` string is already decoded, decoding it again usually makes no sense.